# PROLOG Internals

Tags: prolog

Q: How can I grab every term in PROLOG, then write it out?

Q: something like : prolog_term(X,Functor,Arg1,Arg2) and prolog_term(X,Functor,Arg1) (I'm only interested in /1 and /2 arities).

I think that I want to know how to search-for-and-grab PROLOG terms, without having to RTFM everything.

[I have used Lisp and C (and assembler) extensively (+30 years), and am diving into the deep end of PROLOG now].

Example:

(1) Read in a JSON factbase, e.g.

```
{ fb: 
  [
      { relation: "line", subject: "line6", object: "don't care" },
      { relation: "x1", subject: "line6", object: "160" },
      { relation: "y1", subject: "line6", object: "240" },
      { relation: "x2", subject: "line6", object: "160" },
      { relation: "y2", subject: "line6", object: "360" }
  ]
}
```

(the factbase consists of triples (maybe doubles, when object is "don't care"))

(2) Convert to internal PROLOG format, e.g.

```
 line(line6).
 x1(line6,160).
 y1(line6,240).
 x2(line6,160).
 y2(line6,360).
```

(3) Run some PROLOG rules over the factbase.

(4) Write out all (or some) of the resulting facts in JSON format, e.g. something like:

```
   write_out([line, x1, y1, x2, y2, bounding_box_left, bounding_box_top, bounding_box_right, bounding_box_bottom])
```

(in this example, line/x1/y1/x2/y2 facts were read in, and bounding_box_* facts were generated in step (3)).

[further details available - I'm trying to keep the question short]

Comment: This is a bit of a lazy question (as you know yourself). Those things are quite straight-forward to do, if your Prolog has a JSON library. I will try to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are asking, but if you have the following facts in the Prolog database:

```
line(line6).
x1(line6,160).
y1(line6,240).
x2(line6,160).
y2(line6,360).
```

they are literally "facts of the universe" in which your Prolog program works, so you can "grab them" by trying to prove them:

```
?- x1(line6,X).
X = 160.
```

And you can "grab them" by using the collection predicate bagof/3, setof/3 and findall/3:

```
?- findall(x1(L,X),x1(L,X),All).

All = [x1(line6,160)].
```

Now the above has 5 different predicate names which is excessive, so one would like a fact expressing more with less:

```
% rectangle(Linename,X1,Y1,X2,Y2).

rectangle(rectanglename,line6,160,240,160,360). % needs a unique name
```

Just one fact!

If you are in SWI Prolog you can also deploy "dicts" to great advantage:

```
rectangle(rectanglename,r{x1:160,y1:240,x2:160,y2:360}).
```

Comment: I want to walk through the database.  My first thought is: can I unify against a functor name?

```match(X(A,B)).```

clause/2 is close, but it expects me to specify x1 (for example).

I'm being lazy.  If this isn't possible, I will try something else.

Comment: @paultarvydas You can't unify against the functor name in Prolog. But these facts are supposed to be structured in some way, i.e. have just a few distinct name/arities. OTOH, you can use [clause/2](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clause/2) to collect them all.

Comment: thank you.  I am currently staring at prolog_codewalk.pl - is that a dead end in the making?

Comment: @paultarvydas Unless you want to do program analysis... that's a step too far. Try clause/2 first.

Comment: This whole conversation suffers from confusion.